# Can I extend a python classmethod in multiple places?

Tags: python

I need to extend a classmethod in Python in multiple files.

Let's say, for the sake of decades of tradition, that we have a class `Animal` which has a method called `Animal.eat`

And let's imagine we have a bunch of different modules, `eat`, `swallow` and `taste`

```
# chew/__init__.py
import Animal

def eat():
    print('chewing')
    super(Animal, self).eat()


Animal.eat = eat <------------ This does not work


# swallow/__init__.py
import Animal

def eat():
    print('swallowing')
    super(Animal, self).eat()

Animal.eat = eat <------------ This does not work


# taste/__init__.py
import Animal

def eat():
    print('tasting')
    super(Animal, self).eat()

Animal.eat = eat <------------ This does not work
```

And then we have our `main.py`

```
import Animal
import chew
import swallow
import taste

animal = Animal()
animal.eat()
```

Calling `animal.eat()` should print out

```
chewing
swallowing
tasting
```

But the only thing that happens is that it prints out `tasting`

Can it be done?

Comment: You might want to *decorate* (wrap) the existing method into another one…? Besides that, what you want doesn't appear possible.

Comment: Each time you import a file the top level definitions in that file are executed. In this case you are not "extending" anything, you are _replacing_ the method when you import each file, and the last import wins.

Comment: You'll want to look up how to use class inheritance

Comment: yeah I figured ... so can I extend rather than replace?

Comment: Oh I slightly misunderstood the question then, you'll ideally do this in a slightly different way, will see if I can come up with a quick answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different to go about this, personally I would use some sort of `register` classmethod to add to the `Animal` class from wherever.

```
class Animal(object):

    _EAT_ACTIONS = []

    def eat(self):
        for action in self._EAT_ACTIONS:
            action()

    @classmethod
    def register_eat_action(cls, action):
        cls._EAT_ACTIONS.append(action)


def chew():
    print('chewing')
Animal.register_eat_action(chew)


def swallow():
    print('swallowing')
Animal.register_eat_action(swallow)


def taste():
    print('tasting')
Animal.register_eat_action(taste)


Animal().eat()
# chewing
# swallowing
# tasting
```

With the way you were attempting to do in the question, the working version would be somewhat like this, but I'd suggest not do it as it's quite messy.

```
eat = Animal.eat
def chew(self):
    print('chewing')
    return eat(self)
Animal.eat = chew
```

Edit: Alternative idea with inheritance:

```
class Animal(object):
    Chews = False

    def eat(self):
        if self.Chews:
            print('chewing')

class Dog(Animal):
    Chews = True
```

Comment: FYI the reason I'm doing this is I'm writing a modular code generator that adds different functionalities to a class depending on what is generated

Comment: Ah ok, I'd suggest explore a few different ways once you have something more concrete planned, I just added a quick example of how you might do something similar via inheritance

Answer (score 2):

To *extend* `Animal` you need to define a new class which inherits from `Animal`... it seems like you want to define a base animal class and a bunch of mixins.

You can do this like:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseAnimal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def eat(self):
        return NotImplemented


class Chews:
    def eat(self):
        print('chewing')
        super().eat()


class Swallows:
    def eat(self):
        print('swallowing')
        super().eat()


class Tastes:
    def eat(self):
        print('tasting')
        super().eat()


class Animal(Chews, Swallows, Tastes, BaseAnimal):
    pass
```

and it gives:

```
In [14]: Animal().eat()
chewing
swallowing
tasting
```

To be honest this is a bad use for mixins though, they should provide independent new functionality (e.g. `chew()`, `swallow()`, `taste()` methods) instead of extending existing functionality

So on balance I prefer @Peter's answer for your use case.

But I wanted to demonstrate how to do the kind of inheritance you appeared to be trying to do.